# pandasで AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '_libs' というエラー

Tags: python

```py
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
INP_FILE='sample.csv'
DATA = pd.read_csv(INP_FILE, engine='python')
```

というコードでタイトルのエラーがでます。どこを直せばいいでしょうか。

Comment: どのようにpandasをインストールしましたか？  `python --version` 、 `pip --version` 、 `pip freeze` などを利用して環境についての情報を[追記](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/56800/edit)してみてください。（pipではなくcondaを利用した場合は読み替えてください。）

Comment: 再インストールしたところ治りました　気にかけてくださりありがとうございます